# How to proof that the sequence $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ is monotonic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

I don't know what to do with the square.

Comment: $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}$$

Comment: *Sorry, I omitted the = sign...

Comment: ... examining if the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is greater or less 1, or examing the difference $a_{n+1} - a_n$.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ is increasing, since its derivative $\dfrac1{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$ is always positive.

Comment: Did's comment contains a much better answer.

Comment: Yes, but it is also very good to know. I've nearly started to prove it with induction...

Comment: This is a solid approach!  +1